# is there a built in way to get new hash consisting of only certain key in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Say i have data hash like this:

```
data = [{..}, {..}, {..}]
```

each hash is like this

```
{ :ctiy => 'sdfd', :pop => 33, :best_food=> 'sdfa'....}
```

now how can I get an Array of hashes only containing certain key/value or multiple keys. So take city, if I want new array of hashes containing city only.

I know, I can loop and filter manually but is there a built in method I am missing on.

Comment: you might be looking for Array's map method. Something like data.map{ |i| i[:city] } or data.map{ |i| { city: i[:city] } }

Comment: We'd like to see what effort you put into solving this, either with the minimal code demonstrating what you tried, or where you searched along with an explanation of why those pages didn't help. As is it looks like you want us to write the code for you, which isn't what SO is for. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421.

Comment: Your title and the text following the hash are confusing. On the one hand you refer to "certain key" and on the other, "multiple keys". Which is it you want for an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` will help:

```
original_array_of_hashes.map do |hash|
  { city: hash[:city] }
end
```

If you're using Rails, the `slice` method will be available:

```
original_array_of_hashes.map do |hash|
  hash.slice(:city)
end
```

For multiple keys:

```
# without 'slice'
original_array_of_hashes.map do |hash|
  { key_one: hash[:key_one], key_two: hash[:key_two] }
end

# with 'slice'    
original_array_of_hashes.map do |hash|
  hash.slice(:key_one, :key_two)
end
```

Comment: i guess this is the simplest way and there is no native way to do it

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [{ :city => 'Paris',     :country => 'France', :pop => 2240001 },
       { :city => 'Bardelona', :country => 'Spain',  :pop => 1600002},
       { :city => 'Vancouver', :country => 'Canada', :pop =>  603503 }]

def some_keys(arr, *keys_to_keep)
  arr.map { |h| h.select { |k,_| keys_to_keep.include? k } }
end

some_keys (arr)
  #=> [{}, {}, {}] 
some_keys(arr, :city)
  #=> [{:city=>"Paris"}, {:city=>"Bardelona"}, {:city=>"Vancouver"}] 
some_keys(arr, :city, :pop)
  #=> [{:city=>"Paris", :pop=>2240001},
  #    {:city=>"Bardelona", :pop=>1600002},
  #    {:city=>"Vancouver", :pop=>603503}] 
some_keys(arr, :city, :country, :pop)
  #=> [{:city=>"Paris", :country=>"France", :pop=>2240001},
  #    {:city=>"Bardelona", :country=>"Spain", :pop=>1600002},
  #    {:city=>"Vancouver", :country=>"Canada", :pop=>603503}]
```

This uses [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) (not [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)).

Comment: I don't understand. If `keys_to_keep = []` you want to return `arr`?